# Bit.dev component upload failing

Tags: reactjs, npm, bit.dev

*Original title: Bit.dev installing components from private scopes*

EDIT2: Ok it's starting to be clear that the problem is with bit.dev, even trivial components with no dependencies are 'processing' for hours only to eventually fail:

[image]

Would still love to hear from someone who has experience with bit.dev, if this is normal or can be somehow avoided

*Original question:*

I'm having trouble installing react components that I have on bit.dev via npm.

I created my organisation, with a private scope 'plasmastream'.

I successfully uploaded some components into that scope, and now I want to use them in another project.

When I use the snipet directly from the components page on bit.dev:

```
npm i @bit/eiservices.plasmastream.ps-toast
```

I get npm error:

> npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
> npm ERR! No versions available for @bit/eiservices.plasmastream.ps-toast

Since the component is in private scope, I expected I might need to login in my new project, so i did `bit login` which says I'm already logged in.
So according to this official guide: https://docs.bit.dev/docs/installing-components#configuring-bit-registry I tried to configure my registry manually. But after entering my bit credentials, I get this npm error:

> npm ERR! code E401
> npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - PUT https://node.bit.dev/-/user/org.couchdb.user:mikulashrubes

What am I doing wrong? How can I install components from private bit scopes in other projects with npm?

EDIT: I made the scope with the component public, it seems to make no difference. I notice it says 'Processing' at the component detail page, so maybe it's still not uploaded completely, even after many hours.

Comment: please ensure that your npmrc is configured correctly to fetch components from node.bit.cloud.
also, it seems that you are using a very old version of bit. i suggest looking into the new release - https://bit.dev/docs

Comment: did you find the solution? I'm facing similar kind of issue.

Comment: @SonamAhuja I had to reinstall bit.dev completely and create new workspace, then the issue resolved itself. Not sure what the problem was, I was having so many random technical problems with no error logs from bit.dev that I stopped using it.